# SSIS: How to add Global Variable in Script task?

Tags: ssis

I would like to add the following variable from a script task:

"IndexLocation"
String
Value: "http://www.mypage.com"

'Ex.
dts.variables.add("daf")

--Obviously above does not work

Comment: I realize I can do this by going to SSIS --> Variables, but I would like to do it programatically from a script task.

Comment: Do you want to create the variable in the script?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it in the script task.

Answer (score 0):

You can add variables to a package using Dts.Variables.Add, but I've never tried it myself - wondering why you'd want to create them dynamically in the package rather than set them up in the Variables pane?

Comment: Becasue i have 30 variables i need to add, and I would like to use a loop to add the variables because it would be quicker.

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit re Dts.Variables.Add!  If this is a one-off task, is it not better to create them in the GUI once rather than have to create them dynamically each time the package runs?

Comment: I guess you're right, it just would have been quicker to dynamically make them.

Answer (score 0):

How will these variables be used?
If you're adding them programmatically, other components/tasks will not be aware of them, as you would not have set them up during design time.

Or are you accessing them in another script task, which assumes they have been created?

The general practice is to create variables at design time.

Adding variables at runtime could play havoc on variable locking and other internal ssis workings - you can't guarantee the reliability and accessibility of the variable.